# logging doesn't work using wsgi, no file is created

Tags: python, logging, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm running this flask application to test logging. It's running fine on my local system, but if I run it on the apache server using mod_wsgi, it doesn't work. There is no errors, but, no foo.log is created.

I'm using python 3.5

The code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def foo():
    app.logger.warning('A warning occurred (%d apples)', 42)
    app.logger.error('An error occurred')
    app.logger.info('Info')
    return "foo"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler = RotatingFileHandler('foo.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

the wsgi file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a separate log file for the Python `logging` module when using Apache/mod_wsgi. Instead configure the `logging` module to output messages to the stream handler for the terminal (stdout/stderr). The messages will then be collected in the Apache error log. Use Apache or systems mechanisms for then rotating the log file.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem. I use Apache's mod_wsgi to run a Django application.

At first, the log file is '/tmp/debug.log', there is no error in wsgi's logfile but file "/tmp/debug.log" is not created.

Then, I changes the file to '/var/log/httpd/debug.log', I found errors like this:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/httpd/debug.log'
```

Last , I create a new directory, and change the owner to apache, like this:

```
make /var/log/test
chown apache:apache /var/log/test
```

Now, logfile '/var/log/test/debug.log' is created.

Answer (score 0):

When running via the apache server, the script's pwd isn't necessarily the same path as your terminal's pwd.

Either:

1. Use a full path instead of `foo.log`.

Or:

2. Search your system for `foo.log` and find out where apache decided to place it :)

Comment: You wouldn't find it as the Apache user can't write to what would be the current working directory of Apache when run.